# Android user input validation

Tags: android, kotlin

I have made a tiny Android-project to familiarize myself with user input validation.

The app just has an EditText-control for user input, a button "Compute Result" and a TextView, which shows the result. As input is an integer expected.

The essential part of the code:

```
buttonCompute.setOnClickListener {
  val strInput = inputEditText.text.toString()

  if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(strInput)) {
    val intInput = strInput.toIntOrNull()
    val result = intInput ? .times(10) ? : 0
    resultTextView.text = result.toString()
  } else {
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Please provide a number!",
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
```

It works, but it's a lot of code for such a small tasks.

**Is there a better way? Does someone know further tricks and helpers, to accomplish the validation easier?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's already a `CharSequence.isNotEmpty()` function in the Kotlin standard library, so you could have used that instead of `!TextUtils.isEmpty(strInput)`. But you don't even need to check if it's empty when you're using `toIntOrNull()`. It will return null if the String is empty. Presumably you would want to show the user the message if they somehow entered something that is not a number (although you can set an EditText to accept only integers), so it becomes simply a null-check. The null-check also allows the value to be smart-cast inside the if-statement.

````
buttonCompute.setOnClickListener {
  val intInput = inputEditText.text.toString().toIntOrNull()

  if (intInput != null) {
    resultTextView.text = (intInput * 10).toString()
  } else {
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Please provide a number!",
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
  }
}
```
````